# Why can't mathematica tell me the smallest prime number?

Tags: prime-numbers

I entered

```
MinValue[{Prime[n], n>=1 && Element[n, Integers]}, n]
```

But I just got back what I entered. Why can mathematica not tell me the smallest prime is 2?

Even

```
MinValue[{Prime[n], 1<=n<=10 && Element[n, Integers]}, n]
```

seems to be beyond it, which is bizarre since it only has to check 10 values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably the problem is that the derivative of Prime is undefined in Mathematica

```
D[Prime[n], n]

(*  Derivative[1][Prime][n]  *)
```

Use [`NMinValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NMinValue.html)

```
NMinValue[{Prime[n], 1 <= n}, n, Integers]

(*  2.  *)

NMinValue[{Prime[n], 1 <= n, Element[n, Integers]}, n]

(*  2.  *)
```

[`Round`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Round.html) to taste.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I thought it had more methods than simply taking derivatives.